# Extract value from a text in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one column which has the below content

```
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST="test1.zurich.com")(PORT=1521))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=apps_test1.zurich.com))
(SECURITY=(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY="/u01/zurich/Fdbb48380hdsvh8/data/zurich_WALLET_DIR")
(SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=FALSE)))
```

Now I want to extract only zurich_WALLET_DIR from complete content and if MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY doesn't exist it should give me null value. Can someone help me achieve this?

Tried below but no success

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(HOST,'(.*)(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY)[[:blank:]]*="[[:blank:]]*([^\)]+*)\"\).*','\3',1,1,'i') 
  FROM test;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         HOST,
         '\(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY\s*=\s*"(.*?)"\)',
         1,
         1,
         'i',
         1
       ) AS wallet_dir
from   test;
```

or, more to type but simple string functions are much faster than regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT CASE
       WHEN start_pos > 0 AND end_pos > 0
       THEN SUBSTR(host, start_pos + 22, end_pos - start_pos - 22)
       END AS wallet_dir
FROM   (
  SELECT host,
         INSTR(host, '(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY="', 1) AS start_pos,
         INSTR(host, '")', INSTR(host, '(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY="', 1) + 22)AS end_pos
  from   test
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (host) AS
SELECT '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST="test1.zurich.com")(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=apps_test1.zurich.com))(SECURITY=(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY="/u01/zurich/Fdbb48380hdsvh8/data/zurich_WALLET_DIR")(SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH=FALSE)))' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| WALLET_DIR |
| --- |
| /u01/zurich/Fdbb48380hdsvh8/data/zurich_WALLET_DIR |

---

If you just want the last part of the string then:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         HOST,
         '\(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY\s*=\s*"[^"]*/(.*?)"\)',
         1,
         1,
         'i',
         1
       ) AS wallet_dir
from   test;
```

or:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(wallet_dir, INSTR(wallet_dir, '/', -1) + 1) AS wallet_dir
FROM   (
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN start_pos > 0 AND end_pos > 0
         THEN SUBSTR(host, start_pos + 22, end_pos - start_pos - 22)
         END AS wallet_dir
  FROM   (
    SELECT host,
           INSTR(host, '(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY="', 1) AS start_pos,
           INSTR(host, '")', INSTR(host, '(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY="', 1) + 22)AS end_pos
    from   test
  )
);
```

Which both output:

| WALLET_DIR |
| --- |
| zurich_WALLET_DIR |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RntEECnr)

Comment: Thanks and in case if i want to extract port, i am running below query but it is giving me only PORT=, but i only need value.

 select REGEXP_SUBSTR(HOST,'PORT\s*=\s*',1,1,'i') from dba_db_links

Comment: @Zurich You never match the number for the port `REGEXP_SUBSTR(HOST,'\(PORT\s*=\s*(\d+)\)',1,1,'i', 1)` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kGbfReZw)

Comment: Thanks, It worked as expected, I am trying to understand it more but somehow it is giving me hard time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regex :

```
select regexp_substr(HOST,'MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY=.*\/(.*)"\)',1,1,NULL,1) as Extracted
from mytable;
```

Result :

```
EXTRACTED
zurich_WALLET_DIR
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/UpiGWs9U)